# Retrieving the child from a parent with @MapsId in Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, parent-child

I have two entities - *Item* and *ItemDetails*.  There is a one-to-one mapping between the two - every *Item* has an *ItemDetails*

I'm using `@MapsId` on *ItemDetails* to store the primary key of *Item*, as I understand this is an efficient way to model the relationship.

If I want to get an *Item* with its associated *ItemDetails*, should I:

1. Look at putting a `getItemDetails()` method with a `@JoinColumn()` annotation in *Item*; or
2. Create a DTO for the result of my query, mirroring the *Item* entity but populating the `itemDetails` field with the result of the query?

Comment: By default one to one are egar just call the getter no need join column. Any difficulties you  faced ?